# Doing 'git pull' when sudo required

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab, sudo

I currently have to work on a client server where I need to deploy a project from git but my user does not have write access. I already asked the hoster to change this but have been denied. So the only way to write/deploy is by using sudo, which is making things tricky.

After a lot of searching I figured out how to clone the repo onto the server so it uses my user's ssh key despite acting as root:

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK git clone git@gitlab.com:user/project.git .
```

Now the project has been updated and I need to pull the new version, but fail to find a way to do so.

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK git pull git@gitlab.com:user/project.git
[sudo] password for user: 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Same result appears for other things I tried, like:

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK git pull
sudo git pull
```

How would I need to use git pull so it works with my user's ssh key while using sudo, just as it did when I used git clone?

Comment: Try moving your ssh key into the root user's ssh key folder

Comment: I'm confused on why you need `sudo` on the first place?

Comment: @HRK44 - because the hoster won't give my user write access to the folder for some reason.

Comment: @KuboMD - I already tried that when looking for a solution to clone, no success.

Comment: So you can `sudo` but you can't write into this particular folder where you have to put your code? Can you put your code elsewhere ?

Comment: I can sudo, but when using sudo with git the ssh key authentication does not work as it normally does. Which is why my git clone command above handed my user's key to root to use, but for some reason that doesn't work with git pull.